# Out Of Memory Exception when caching bitmaps

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory, dalvik

I am designing an application where i want to store 12 bitmaps in memory for quick access. I am retrieving these images from the disk cache or downloading them if they are not present. The issue that i am having is after a few times of running the activity that does the caching my app crashes in the OnCreate Method with the exception

This exeption occurs only when The result from Runtime.getRuntime ().totalMemory() is over 66265056

`05-10 15:32:44.831: E/dalvikvm-heap(26563): Out of memory on a 6554896-byte allocation.
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x411d96a0 self=0x411c2988
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   | sysTid=26563 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075505232
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=872 stm=205 core=0
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:592)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3424)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3357)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:426)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.afewguys.photofrenzy.activities.PreGameActivity_.setContentView(PreGameActivity_.java:48)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.afewguys.photofrenzy.activities.PreGameActivity_.onCreate(PreGameActivity_.java:31)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-10 15:32:44.831: I/dalvikvm(26563):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 15:32:44.831: A/libc(26563): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0031fb00 (code=1), thread 26584 (uys.photofrenzy)
05-10 15:32:44.831: A/libc(26563): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 26563 (uys.photofrenzy)`

I am storing the bitmaps in the LRUCache which is recommended from the Android Docs. And DiskLRUCache for the disk cacheing. I was unable to use the memory cache portion of DiskLRUCache because it was failing to retrieve images at random times. I do the caching in the extended Application class

```
     final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
     final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            } 
            @Override
            protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key, Bitmap oldBitmap, Bitmap newBitmap) {
                oldBitmap.recycle();
                oldBitmap = null;
            }
        };
}

public static void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}
public static void clearCache(){
    mMemoryCache.evictAll();
    System.gc();
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

The Activity for the cacheing

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.afewguys.photofrenzy", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File diskCacheLocation = getExternalFilesDir(C.thumbNailDir);
    BitmapLruCache.Builder builder = new BitmapLruCache.Builder(this);
    builder.setMemoryCacheEnabled(false).setMemoryCacheMaxSizeUsingHeapSize();
    builder.setDiskCacheEnabled(true).setDiskCacheLocation(diskCacheLocation);
    mCache = builder.build();
    game = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getGameEntryWithId(getIntent().getExtras().getString(C.bundleGame));
    mCache = builder.build();       
    PhotoFrenzyApplication.clearCache();
    new loadSingleView().execute();
}


class loadSingleView extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int round = 0;
    int numPhoto = 0; 
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        PhotoFrenzyApplication.clearHash();
        for(PhotoRound pr:game.getDbPhotoRounds()){
            round++;
            numPhoto = 0;
            for(Photo p:pr.getDBPhotos()){
                CacheableBitmapDrawable cView = mCache.get(p.getThumbNailLink());
                Bitmap bm = (cView != null) ? mCache.get(p.getThumbNailLink()).getBitmap() : null;
                if(bm != null){
                    PhotoFrenzyApplication.addBitmapToMemoryCache(p.getThumbNailLink(),mCache.get(p.getThumbNailLink()).getBitmap());
                    mCache.remove(p.getThumbNailLink());
                }
                else
                    PhotoFrenzyApplication.addBitmapToMemoryCache(p.getThumbNailLink(),loadNewPhoto(p.getThumbNailLink()));     PhotoFrenzyApplication.addImageToHash(loadNewPhoto(p.getOriginalLink()),p.getOriginalLink());
                System.out.println("Memory : " + Runtime.getRuntime ().totalMemory());
                publishProgress();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        updateRoundPhotosLoaded(round,++numPhoto);
    }        
    @Override       
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        startGame();
    }
}
```

I have verified that when evicting the old bitmaps recycle is getting called. I cannot find where the memory is being held up

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest not to keep such big Bitmaps in memory. 6554896 bytes = 1280x1280 image, which won't fit most displays.

You seem to have caching in two places: `Application` and `Activity`, which is odd.

I suggest using MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) to search for memory leaks of `Activity`. If you find more than 1, you have your root cause of crashes.

Other than that there are some evil things in your code like `oldBitmap.recycle();` or `System.gc();`.